# dynamic drop down how to show success using css (tic icon)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have created dynamic drop down

- loading second drop down using first selected value
- now what i need is i need to display the following css(tic icon) next to first drop down

### code

```
<span id="checkmark">
        <div id="circle"></div>
        <div id="stem"></div>
        <div id="kick"></div>
    </span>
```

the CSS is added in JSfiddle
and full [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sanoj908572/4yL0871f/)

i need like this when second drop down is loaded i need output like this[image]

Comment: @MathiasaurusRex not inside i need next to select element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it like this http://jsfiddle.net/4yL0871f/2/

The CODE

```
$(function () {
     $("#text-one").change(function () {
         $("#checkmark").css({display: 'inline-block'});
         $("#text-two").show();
         $("#text-two").load("textdata/" + $(this).val() + ".txt");
     });
 });
```

HTML

```
<div id="page-wrap">
     <h1>Pulls from text files</h1>

    <div class="select-wrap">
        <select id="text-one">
            <option selected value="base">Please Select</option>
            <option value="beverages">Beverages</option>
            <option value="snacks">Snacks</option>
        </select> 
        <span id="checkmark">
            <div id="circle"></div>
            <div id="stem"></div>
            <div id="kick"></div>
        </span>

    </div>
    <select id="text-two" style="display :none">
        <option>Please choose from above</option>
    </select>
</div>
```